# Prevent render method to re render in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to stop render method to re-render on state change.

I have routes file as follows :

```
var routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="registration" component={RegistrationPage}/>
    </Route>
);
```

Then I have my main app component :

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            lang: 1
        };
    },

    changeLang: function(name, event){

        switch (name){
            case "fra" :
                this.setState({lang: 2});
                break;
            case "ger" :
                this.setState({lang: 3});
                break;
            case "ned" :
                this.setState({lang: 4});
                break;
            default:
                this.setState({lang: 1});
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        var currentRoute = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1);
        var header = currentRoute === "" ? <Header onClick={this.changeLang} lang={this.state.lang}/> : <HeaderCompact currentRoute={currentRoute} onClick={this.changeLang} lang={this.state.lang}/>;
        return (
            <div>
                {header}
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { lang: this.state.lang })}
                <Footer lang={this.state.lang}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

I want to disable re-render if click is happend in  component.
HeaderCompact component is for my registration page and when I click to change a language on registration page the initial state in App component changes and render function re-renders and I get again the index page route.

What I want is if I click on to the flag to change a language in headerCompact component that the state in my App component changes but that route stay the same i.e that (`<Route path="registration" component={RegistrationPage}/>`) stays and that it's not changed to (`<IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>`).

**EDIT**

My HeaderCompact component where the problem occurs is :

```
<div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <ul className="langAndBtn">
                                <li className={phoneNrLi}>
                                    <Link to="/" className={hideNed} style={{marginRight: 10}} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'ned')}><img src="../images/languages/nl.png" /></Link>
                                    <Link to="/" className={hideEng} style={{marginRight: 10}} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'eng')}><img src="../images/languages/gb.png" /></Link>
                                    <Link to="/" className={hideFra} style={{marginRight: 10}} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'fra')}><img src="../images/languages/fr.png" /></Link>
                                    <Link to="/" className={hideGer} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'ger')}><img src="../images/languages/ger.png" /></Link>
                                </li>
                                {regButton}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate)? You can have it return `false` under any circumstances you define and your component will not update.

Comment: Based on the code you've posted calling `changeLang()` should *not* change the route, so calling `render()` should not change the header. What code is changing the route?

Comment: @Aaron I'm not sure. I updated my question with code from HeaderCompact component.